# BoxLayout and Graphical

Tags: java, boxlayout, data-entry

I'm hoping to get a working example of how I could can implement box layout to the code provided below. At the moment I am only familiar with border layout but this project I cant figure out how to add 5 entry fields that can have functions applied to them after numbers might be entered. Currently the code for the graphical side is really messy but it is mostly place holders, though the format is what I want.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GradeFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame GradeFrame = new JFrame("Check Your Grades!");
    GradeFrame.setLocation(450, 150);
    GradeFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 625));
    GradeFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    Font font1 = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 32);

    JPanel section1 = new JPanel();
    JTextArea entry1 = new JTextArea
    ("Place holder for user's name and class");
    entry1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 110));
    entry1.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    entry1.setLineWrap(true);
    entry1.setEditable(false);
    entry1.setFont(font1);
    section1.add(entry1);

    JPanel section2 = new JPanel();
    JTextField entry2 = new JTextField("Current Grade: ");
    entry2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 110));
    entry2.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    entry2.setEditable(false);
    entry2.setFont(font1);
    section2.add(entry2);

    JPanel section3 = new JPanel();
    JTextField entry3 = new JTextField("Grades entered: ");
    entry3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 110));
    entry3.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    entry3.setEditable(false);
    entry3.setFont(font1);
    section3.add(entry3);

    JPanel section4 = new JPanel();
    JTextField entry4 = new JTextField
    ("graphic place holder");
    entry4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 110));
    entry4.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    entry4.setEditable(false);
    entry4.setFont(font1);
    section4.add(entry4);

    JPanel section5 = new JPanel();
    JTextField entry5 = new JTextField("Data entry area");
    entry5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
    entry5.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    entry5.setEditable(false);
    entry5.setFont(font1);
    section5.add(entry5);

    JPanel section6 = new JPanel();
    section6.add(section1);
    section6.add(section2);
    section6.add(section3);
    section6.add(section4);

    GradeFrame.add(section5, BorderLayout.WEST);
    GradeFrame.add(section6);

    GradeFrame.pack();

    GradeFrame.setVisible(true);
    GradeFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    }
}
```

I am trying to get some code implemented that has the functions of this second section of code. Some of the code here was provided by another user from my last question.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeData {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

int count = 0;
double grade = 0;
String user;
boolean enter = true;
String name;
String enterAgain;
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
name = userInput.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter a grade: ");
grade = userInput.nextDouble();
userInput.nextLine(); //add this to your program

System.out.println("Would you like to continue entering grades? (y/n)");
enterAgain = userInput.nextLine();

while(enter){
    if(enterAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        System.out.println("Please enter another grade: ");
        grade = userInput.nextDouble();
    }
    else if(enterAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
        System.out.println("Ok. Thank you for entering grades.");
        break; 
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Sorry, you can only enter (y/n)");
        break; 
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: `At the moment I am only familiar with border layout` - then you can start with the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples. You can download the demos and play with them. Don't forget you can nest panels each using a different layout manager.

Comment: `GradeFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` - the default layout manager for a frame is a BorderLayout, so you don't need that statement. Also you would NOT set the layout AFTER you add components to the panel. You set the layout BEFORE you start adding components. Also you don't need to create a panel for your each text field. You can add each text field directly to the "section6" panel.